# How to adjust gradient color by RGB or HSB

Tags: colors, gradient

I'm trying to make a bar with gradient color updownward, I set 3 points as stated in the bar. Now the picture seems good, but I don't know how to automatically generate these color mathematically, by RGB or HSB? I'm having trouble with the rule of this kind of art thing.

I was intending to do it with RGB but I found it hard to do. But with HSB, I changed "S" and it makes a little sense as shown in picture.

My question is: How to calculate these **three colors** based on **ONE given color**, makes the gradient natural?

Thanks in advance, this has nothing to do with code but I think it definitely has a mathematical solution(formula).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's no general rule for how to do this and different possibilities to get to a (subjectively pleasing) result.

I copied your colors [here](http://www.workwithcolor.com/hsl-color-picker-01.htm?cp=C33C35&ch=3-57-49&cb=C33C35,D58789,DC4D4A,FFFFFF,E77A0C,F8BB7D,F49637,FFFFFF,FFFFFF,FFFFFF) for analysis but didn't find a pattern in your choice. My solution would be to find a pleasing distance of (relative) luminance. To adabt to your example I chose one arbitrary color, then increased the Lum value by 18% for the second color and for the third one I subtracted 10% Lum again.

Do you like this solution?